# What is long-term impact of decorative boulders near a house foundation wall?

Tags: walls, basement, stone, gardening

I live in 1500 sq ft house with unfinished basement. I'm planning to put some stones outside house near walls (in garden). And have a plan to put some plants around it (for decoration).

My concern is the stones are heavy with roughly 2 to 3 tons each. I'm planning to put 4 stones. Does it have any long term impact on the structure of walls of basement? Does it put any kind pressure from outside?

Comment: how big are the stones in shape if it was within a foot of the foundation and a 3 ton monolith type stone there may be a problem. A large bolder would cover a much larger area and probably not cause any concern.

Comment: @EdBeal I'm planning to put them 3 to 4 feet (roughly) away from wall. And each stone is roughly 2 to 3 tones. I hope I answered your question.

Comment: @EdBeal The house is few years old now and soil is in stable state.

Answer (score 2):

As requested:
That far away I cant see any problem. Your soil had to be stable enough to put the basement in. I would not even worry about a monolith that far away.